# No results on Google Search in normal mode, but results in incognito?

Tags: google-search

In normal browsing mode, when I search for "pimp scroll bar html", I get no results:

[image: normal]

However on Incognito mode (for Google Chrome), suddenly I get results:
[image: incognito]

I disabled all my extensions, and yet the problem is still there. Why does this happen?

EDIT: I tried logging out of my google account, and for some *BIZZARE* reason, now the search works properly. Why would me being logged in stop the searches from appearing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a really silly situation.

The answer really only deserves a single line: *I had safe search turned on*.

Somehow I took a screenshot of that, and *didn't notice*.

(In the 0.0001% chance somebody needs to know, you can just turn safe search off by clicking the gear at the top right of the page (under your account picture)).

Comment: And thanks to your silly situation, the next time someone has it and googles what to do, they immediately find out how silly it is :)

Comment: How silly am I? I'm really silly. That dude "I" should stop being silly.

Comment: I thought they got rid of safe search and made it so that "adult content" was always filtered unless explicitly stated in the search query?

Answer (score 1):

That's not the only case.

It happens for that reason or even if you participate to the program "custom ads".

Nonetheless, Google (Alphabet?) has different servers and different domains around the globe.

Try this
https://www.google.com/webhp?source=desktop&devloc=0&gws_rd=cr

or this
https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en

Any difference?

Of course there are, because we deleted the parameter "&ei=your-crypted-personal-identifier" from the address (and a few other things).
Websites are really "naked software" and you can interact with them easily; this will change their behavior, thus, you **can** have different results based on many factors.